# Select a value for every user even if there is none sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of banking transactions and I'm trying to create a view that holds the balance for each user registered based on card type. So even if the user has never made a transaction, I want it to show as

```
---------------------
| user_id | balance |
---------------------
| 1       | 0.0     |
---------------------
```

But when I do a query where there are no transactions:

```
SELECT u.id AS user_id, SUM(amount) AS balance FROM `transactions` t
INNER JOIN users u
ON t.from_id = u.id
WHERE card_type = 'debit'
```

It returns:

```
---------------------
| user_id | balance |
---------------------
| null    | null    |
---------------------
```

Therefore, how do I go about retrieving the first result with no transactions in the table, if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for an outer join -- and `group by`:

```
SELECT u.id AS user_id, COALESCE(SUM(t.amount), 0) AS balance
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
    transactions t
    ON t.from_id = u.id AND
       t.card_type = 'debit'
GROUP BY u.id;
```

Notes:

- You want all users, so it is the first table in the `LEFT JOIN`.
- You want exactly one row per user, so you want `GROUP BY u.id`.
- You are filtering on the *second* table, so the filter goes in the `ON` clause.

Comment: Yes this would work but it would leave the balance null, could I set a default value if there is none, like 0?

Comment: I added `COALESCE` so: `SELECT u.id AS user_id, COALESCE(SUM(t.amount), 0) AS balance
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
    transactions t
    ON t.from_id = u.id AND
       t.card_type = 'debit'
GROUP BY u.id;`